# Type Void[] Array Not Assignable to Type Void

Tags: typescript

I expect type void[] to be compatible with type void. Specifically, when using Promise.all.

```
class Foo {
  delete(): Promise<void> {
    // do delete
    return Promise.resolve();
  }
  deleteMany(list: Foo[]): Promise<void> {
    return Promise.all(list.map((x) => x.delete()));
  }
```

typescript error:

> 'Type 'Promise<void[]>' is not assignable to type 'Promise<void>'. Type 'void[]' is not assignable to type 'void'.'

I can solve this two ways that I know of:

1. Mark deleteMany as returning Promise<void[]>.
2. Promise chain to Promise.all, to return a resolved promise. e.g.

   ```
   return Promise.all(list.map((x) => x.delete())).then(() => Promise.resolve());
   ```

The second one is worse, since that bit of code executes in JavaScript, but the first one is confusing to developers. Does Typescript have poor support for Promise.all or is it omitted from their documentation? Anyone find a better solution?

Comment: Why not just mark `deleteMany` as returning `Promise<void[]>`? That's not poor support, that's what a `Promise.all` call returns...

Comment: As @MikeMcCaughan suggests.. I agree.. Promise.all returns a Promise of array of the type, which in this case it is void

Comment: 3rd option: Just leave the return type off entirely. The compiler will infer it and raise an error if it is used incorrectly. Go with 1 or 3, 2 does not make sense.

Comment: From the MDN docs: "If all of the passed-in promises fulfill, Promise.all is fulfilled with an array of the values from the passed-in promises, in the same order as defined in the iterable." This is the expected result of Promise.all -- a promise that resolves to an array containing the fulfilled values which in this case will all be void. It would be confusing to developers to type it with anything BUT Promise<void[]>

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Because consumers shouldn't care about implementation detail. I like Aluan's suggestion the best.

sbking You're absolutely right, however, I find arrays filled with void types terribly unhelpful.

Comment: @JerroydM. So `Promise<void[]>` is an implementation detail, but `Promise<void>` is not? Also, it's not an implementation detail; it's the contract that your method is providing. Aluan's suggestion doesn't change that; it just makes it implicit rather than explicit. Personally I think the whole question much ado about nothing.

Answer (score 8):

The 1 (Mark deleteMany as returning `Promise<void[]>`) is absolutely ok at least for me.

However, you can use `async`/`await` if you really want to return `Promise<void>`:

```
class Foo {
  delete(): Promise<void> {
    // do delete
    return Promise.resolve();
  }
  async deleteMany(list: Foo[]): Promise<void> {
    await Promise.all(list.map((x) => x.delete()));
  }
```

The function will behave exactly the same way.

Answer (score 3):

`void` is [incompatible with any other type except](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#void) `null` and `undefined` by design, so it's incompatible with `void[]`.

You could use `Promise<{}>` as result type of `deleteMany`, that is, promise resolving to empty object. It works, because empty object type has no properties (so it can not meaningfully be used in any way), and, because it has no properties (again), it could be assigned almost anything, including `void[]`:

```
class Foo {
    delete(): Promise<void> {
        // do delete
        return Promise.resolve();
    }
    deleteMany(list: Foo[]): Promise<{}> {
        return Promise.all(list.map((x) => x.delete()));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the promise doesn't actually contains data, you can safely cast like this:

```
class Foo {
  delete(): Promise<void> {
    // do delete
    return Promise.resolve();
  }
  deleteMany(list: Foo[]): Promise<void> {
    return (Promise.all(list.map((x) => x.delete()))) as unknown as Promise<void>;
  }
}
```

The intermediate `unknown` can trick the TS compiler to allow casting